# Filtering spatial data based on a distance matrix from large datasets

Tags: performance, r

I am using a R function to spatially filter location points. There are five steps in the function: 1) calculate the distance between all points, 2) for each point, define the number of neighboring points within a given distance, 3) define the points with the greatest number of neighboring points within the given distance, 4) randomly remove one of the points defined in the step 3, 5) repeat the steps 2 to 4 until no point has a nearest neighboring point closer than the given distance.

The code works, but it is too slow and causes memory problems using large datasets because it uses a distance matrix to perform calculations. Currently, I work with a dataset of 100,000 locations, which gives a matrix of 100,000 rows and 100,000 columns. Is there a way to improve this code to work with large datasets. Here is the code:

```
N = 100
data <- data.frame(long = runif(N, min = -130, max = -60), lat = runif(N, min = 16, max = 60))
## head(data)
test <- data_filtering(data = data, filtering_distance = 1000, repetitions = 100)

data_filtering <- function (data, filtering_distance, repetitions){
  
  ## Convert data to spatial data
  data_sp <- terra::vect(data, geom = c("long", "lat"), crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
  
  ## Create a list containing the filtered dataset
  filtered_data_list <- vector("list", repetitions)
  ## Calculate the distance between all points
  init_dist_mat <- terra::distance(data_sp, data_sp)/1000 # distance in km
  ## Find the points within the filtering distance
  init_dist_mat <- init_dist_mat < filtering_distance
  ## Do not include the diagonal values
  diag(init_dist_mat) <- FALSE

  ## Calculate the number of neighboring points within the filtering distance
  init_points_within_distance <- rowSums(init_dist_mat)
  ## Create a condition vector
  init_selected_points <- rep(TRUE, length(init_points_within_distance))
  
  ## Loop over the number of repetitions
  for(repetition in seq_len(repetitions)) {
    
    dis_mat <- init_dist_mat
    points_within_distance <- init_points_within_distance
    selected_points <- init_selected_points
    
    while(any(dis_mat) && sum(selected_points) > 1){
      
      ## Find the maximum number of neighboring points within the filtering distance
      removed_points <- which(points_within_distance == max(points_within_distance))
      
      if(length(removed_points) > 1){
        ## Select a neighboring point
        removed_points <- sample(removed_points, 1)
      }
      
      ## Remove the neighboring point
      points_within_distance <- points_within_distance - dis_mat[, removed_points]
      
      ## Update the objects
      points_within_distance[removed_points] <- 0
      dis_mat[removed_points, ] <- FALSE
      dis_mat[,removed_points] <- FALSE
      selected_points[removed_points] <- FALSE
    }
    
    ## Define the data frame with filtered data
    filtered_data <- data[selected_points, , drop = FALSE]
    colnames(filtered_data) <- c("Longitude", "Latitude")
    filtered_data_list[[repetition]] <- filtered_data  
  }
  
  ## Reorder the elements of the list
  filtered_data_list <- filtered_data_list[order(unlist(lapply(filtered_data_list, nrow)), decreasing = TRUE)]
  return(filtered_data_list)
}
```

Comment: Since you only seem to be checking points within a certain distance from each other, can you use a sparse matrix, such as Compressed Sparse Row format? And if distances are the same in either direction, you can optimize by calculating them only with the lower-numbered location first, and swap if necessary.

Comment: Can you speed up the within-distance check by using a bounding box, say, within plus or minus five degrees of latitude and longitude, and skip all pairs that fail, immediately?

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I don't know the sparse matrices, such as Compressed Sparse Row format. Are these matrices used in the "MatrixExtra" package? Currently, I am explory the "big.matrix" function of the "bigmemory" package.

Comment: Steps (1) & (2) are quadratic insanity, where you do a ton of work and then discard most of it based on distance threshold. You're tackling a solved problem. Put the (lat,lng)'s into an **indexed** [postgres](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/geography.html) DB. Then a self-join with a [WHERE](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) clause will efficiently produce the point pairs you require.

Comment: I don't understand what the desired outcome is? You seem to end up with a list of 100 dataframes, with around 20 long-lat points. The distance between these points still seem to be over the filtering distance. Could you please provide a description of what the end point of this code should look like? Is it the initial table (`data`) with certain points removed?